# how to find albums using mysql query having 2 assets for each of its tracks

Tags: mysql, database

I want a mysql query for following scenario
I have following database structure

```
1] table 'albums'  Columns  'id', 'name'
2] table 'tracks'  Columns  'id', 'title', 'album_id'   (album has many tracks)
3] table 'assets'  Columns  'id', 'track_id'   (track has many assets)
```

I want to find out all the albums such that, all the tracks of that album must have at least 2 assets.

For following test data 
albums

```
'id'    'name'
  1      Album 1
  2      Album 2
```

tracks

```
  'id'    'title'        'album_id'
   1      Track 1       1
   2      Track 2       1
   3      Track 3       2
   4      Track 4       2
```

assets

```
'id'  'track_id'
 1      1
 2      1
 3      2
 4      2
 5      3
 6      3
 7      4
```

So my query o/p should be

```
'id'    'name'
  1      Album 1
```

As `Album 1`  has two tracks `Track 1` and `Track 2` and both of these tracks have `2 assets` whereas `Track 4` of `Album 2` have only `1 asset`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try:

```
SELECT    a.id,
          a.name
FROM      albums a
JOIN      tracks b ON a.id = b.album_id
LEFT JOIN (
          SELECT   track_id
          FROM     assets
          GROUP BY track_id
          HAVING   COUNT(*) >= 2
          ) c ON b.id = c.track_id
GROUP BY  a.id, 
          a.name
HAVING    COUNT(*) = COUNT(c.track_id)
```

---

[*SQLFiddle Demo*](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/7aaa9/2)